# Jquery mobile on key press "Go"?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

This code works when pressing enter on a PC keyboard `if (event.keyCode == 13)` but this doesn't work on mobile phone's "Go" button. What is the keyCode that works for both `Enter` and `Go` key?

Comment: Please post the code. Are you trying to catch a form submission?

Comment: @StoicJester As much as possible I don't want to use `<form>`, I just want to get the value of a text field when `Enter` or `Go` is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find this documentation for the Android keyboard: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_ENTER

I don't know if those codes are consistent with what is passed to the web browser from the keyboard.

My recommendation would be to output the keycodes to a block of text as you enter them, then you could just test it out manually.

Where you are testing for `event.keyCode == 13`, add something that looks like this:

`document.body.innerHTML += "new code: " + event.keyCode + "<br/>"`

Then you can hit the "Go" key a few times and see what code it gives you.